# How to vertically center in table only text with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So i have this demo :https://fiddle.jshell.net/ghyy6ntf/
Problem is that with flex i centered text and image but i cant put title and subtitle one bellow another. So i need to have image on left side and title and description verticaly centered in table td but one bellow another.

```
.product_box{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the ***shortest*** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: It is vertically centered.